# Odoo/Python: modules dependencies gone wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dependencies, odoo, python-module

I have these modules:

`base_module`, `module_1`
`base_module_extend`, `module_2`.

These  modules have such dependencies:

- `module_1` depends on `base_module`.
- `base_module_extend` depends on `base_module`.
- `module_2` depends on `base_module_extend`.

If `module_1` and `module_2` are not installed at the same time, then everything works fine, but if they are installed, then dependencies change in the order those modules were installed.

So for example if I install `module_2` and then `module_1`, when I start using `module_2` when you call `super` in that module code, it finds class that was defined in `base_module` instead of `base_module_extend` first and then some things break, because it does not find some attributes/arguments which are defined in `base_module_extend`.

And if I install in opposite order: first install `module_1` and `module_2`, then it when I use `module_2`, it works fine, because it calls correct classes from `super`.

Is there a way to make those modules call correct parent classes if they are installed both without caring at the order they were installed?

Or is it limitation and there is nothing you can do about it?..

**Update**

Example of what is broken if you install in wrong order (the first scenario):

This is a method defined in `base_module`:

```
def export_data(self, export_time=fields.Datetime.now()):
    """
    This method can be overridden to implement custom data exportation
    """
    self.ensure_one()
    res = []
    return res
```

This is a method that was changed in `module_1`:

```
def export_data(self, export_time=fields.Datetime.now()):
    res = super(SFTPImportExport, self).export_data(export_time)
    if self.process == 'custom_qty_available':
        res = self._export_qty_available(export_time)
    elif self.process == 'custom_sale':
        res = self._export_sale(export_time)
    return res
```

This is a method that was changed in `base_module_extend`:

```
def export_data(
        self, export_time=fields.Datetime.now(), external_data=False):
    """
    Overrides export_data to be able to provide external_data that
    is already generated and can be directly returned to be used in export
    @param export_time: time of export
    @param external_data: used to bypass specific export
    method and directly use data provided
    """
    res = super(SFTPImportExport, self).export_data(export_time)

    return res
```

And this is a same method that was changed in `module_2`:

```
def export_data(self, export_time=fields.Datetime.now(), external_data=False):
    """
    Adds support for custom_invoice process
    """
    res = super(SFTPImportExport, self).export_data(export_time=export_time, external_data=external_data)
    if self.process == 'custom_invoice':
        res = external_data
    return res
```

**Update2**

When last method version (the one that is defined in `module_2`) is executed, I get this error:

```
"/opt/odoo/projects/project/sftp_import_export_extend/models/sftp_import_export.py", line 47, in export_sftp

    export_time=now, external_data=external_data)

ValueError: "export_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'external_data'" while evaluating

u'invoice_validate()'
```

So it looks like it get wrong parent class, the one that does not have such keyword argument

Comment: I would like to read the code of these modules, since sometimes is the way the functions are overwrited, in your examples if there is a function defined with the same name in the 4 modules, all 4 should run (actually it may change if its an on_change or something that depends on a view).

Comment: I have updated my question with method. That method does not depend on view.

Comment: Pretty strange case, i dont like that use of hierarchy since external_data is not on the first two modules, anyway it should work, try to log in module_2 super(SFTPImportExport, self) before calling the function to see what kind of object / model it is.

Comment: Could you give us more code? I think you are making inherit, and what inherit do is changing things in super, so from child we can add functionality to parent, so in your case in first scenario, you are setting function from model module2 and then module1, modul1 is overriding module2-s function with same name. and is second scenario you are making function overloading i think and thats why it's working.
I'm not very sure about my answer but maybe it will help you

Answer (score 0):

*super()* tends to choose wrong(unexpected) parent in Python. As an alternative you can use direct call of Python function from the desired superclass, instead of using *super()*, this is much more reliable way.

I do not know a directory structure and source file names of your Odoo module, so I'll try to guess the structure approximately and give you description of what should be done. Please adapt it to your case (to have correct module name, source file name, etc).

If the desired python class, say named as `SFTPImportExport` that contains the desired `export_data` method is defined in the following source file inside the `base_module_extend` Odoo module (relative path): `base_module_extend/models/somefile.py` than, instead of using `super()`, you can call it directly like:

- import desired supercalss:

  ```
  from openerp.base_module_extend.models.somefile import SFTPImportExport as ParentSFTPImportExport
  ```
- and call it's method directly:

  ```
  ParentSFTPImportExport.export_data(self, export_time=export_time, external_data=external_data)
  ```

In this case the exact function you desire will be called, as you directly refer to it. I suggest to do the same, i.e. directly call desired function, in the both modules, to be sure that they never mix their target functions.